# allow phone to access PCs localhost at specific port

Tags: windows-10, firewall

I'm running a `NodeJS` app running at port `3001`. I want to be able to access that website from my cell phone.

My local ip is: `10.0.0.27` and my cell phone is `10.0.0.7` I disabled the firewall and it worked. I created an inbound rule that exposed port `3001` to the world (or so I thought I did) that did NOT work.

I know it's a firewall issue, I'm just not sure how to create the inbound rule to allow `10.0.0.27:3001` to be access but not blanketing a port `80` allow or disabling the firewall.

This is `Windows 10`

Firewall setup:

- Local Port: 3001
- Remote Port: All ports
- Any IPs, any users
- Public, Private and Domain

Comment: How can anybody help you if you don't post what operating system you're running? And, please post the firewall rule you setup?

Comment: And what firewall for that matter?

Comment: @Appleoddity updated. thought the tag would have been enough

Comment: Are you sure the NodeJS app ONLY uses 3001 and nothing else? I mean the initial connection may use port 3001 but it may also spawn and use other ports?

Comment: for localhost, i'm forcing it to run on `3001`

Comment: When your setup the firewall rule you also have to specify which location it applies to - public, work or domain. Did you choose one or just choose all? The rule is specific to which kind of network Windows thinks it is on.

Answer (score 4):

It does appear to be a firewall issue. Can you be absolutely sure it only requires port 3001 and it is TCP?

It sounds like you set the rule up right, but let's double check.

1. Open Control Panel -> Windows Firewall
2. Click on `Advanced Settings`
3. Select `Inbound Rules`
4. Click `New Rule`
5. Type of rule = `Port` then click `Next`
6. Rule applies to `TCP`, and specify port `3001` then click `Next`
7. Action = `Allow the connection` then click `Next`
8. When does this rule apply? Choose all - `Domain` `Private` and `Public` then click `Next`
9. Give your new rule a name and click `Finish`

That's it. It should work.

If it doesn't work then one of two things are going on I would say. Your connection needs more than just port 3001. If this is the case, disable the firewall again and confirm the application works. While the application is connected, run the following command from an administrative command prompt: `netstat -abn | more`. Page through the results and identify the listening ports or active connections associated with your endpoint. This might show something you weren't aware of.

Otherwise, some other piece of software on the computer may be blocking something. Just make sure no other security software could be blocking things.

Comment: I can not thank you enough...this saved my life :)

Comment: Specific information for Java and Android: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51889837/7389293